# How to display the microop in the reorder buffer for gem5?

Tags: gem5

When debugging gem5, I want to know what microops are in the reorder buffer, instruction queue or decoding queue? Is there any way to do it?
When debugging with gdb, when I use `p queuename`, the display is similar to

```
    {std::queue wrapping: std::deque with 8 elements = {{data = 0x23e5d700}, {data = 0x23ead180}, {
          data = 0x23e722c0}, {data = 0x2460a580}, {data = 0x37ecc00}, {data = 0x23ef2580}, {data = 0x23eb8ec0}, {
          data = 0x23ec2b00}}, std::queue wrapping: std::deque with 0 elements,

  std::queue wrapping: std::deque with 0 elements, std::queue wrapping: std::deque with 0 elements}
```

But I want it to show specific micro-operations such as mov add.